# Context free grammar for {a^mb^n | m ≠ n}

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I need to find a context-free grammar for the above expression, $a^{m}b^{n}$ for the set $L = \left\{{a, b}\right\}$, but I am having difficulty accounting for the condition $m \neq n$.

This is what I have so far, but it clearly doesn't satisfy the above condition:

$\begin{align}
   &S \rightarrow aAb &\\
   &S \rightarrow a &\\
   &S \rightarrow b &\\
   &A \rightarrow aA &\\
   &A \rightarrow bA &\\
   &A \rightarrow \lambda \\
\end{align}$

I have spent about an hour on this, and haven't found a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: There are quite a few very similar questions around, e.g. [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9831/context-free-grammar-for-language-l) and [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9804/context-free-grammar-for-language-l-aibj-mid-i-j-ge-0-i-ne-2j).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Start with a CFG for the language $\{ a^{n+t} b^n : n \geq 0, t \geq 1 \}$.

Comment: Does this really count as an answer?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and I did try to find a grammar for this, but I run into the same problem -- how to ensure that $m$ and $n$ are not the same number. With my above grammar, any number of $a$s or $b$s is valid, and $a$s and $b$s can have the same degree, which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @PålGD This looks like a homework question to me, so my (personal) policy is to only give hints. If you disagree, you can always downvote.

Comment: @Dylan The trick is to take $m = n+t$ where $t \geq 1$. This ensures that $n \neq m$.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong... I wasn't taking account of the original definition in that all $a$ characters appear before $b$ characters. I think I have it now, thank you for your help.