# Context-free grammar for $\{a^x b^y : x \neq y\}$

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

I am trying to create a context free grammar in [Extended Backus–Naur form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form), which starts with a non-empty sequence of `a`'s and is followed by a non-empty sequence of `b`'s. With the special condition that the number of `b`'s has to be **unequal** to the number of `a`'s.

Thus, the grammar should generate words like:

- `aaaabbb`
- `aaabb`
- `abbb`

---

So basically I could do something like this:

$\ G=(N,T,P,S)$

$\ N = \{S\}$

$\ T = \{a,b\}$

$\ P = \{S=aa(S|\epsilon)b\}$

But then the words would always have $\ 2n$ `a`'s and n `b`'s:

- `aab`
- `aaaabb`
- `aaaaaabbb`

So how is it possible to make the number of `a`'s **uncorrelated** of the number of `b`'s, without being equal?

Comment: Hint: if $n\ne m$ then either $n\lt m$ or $n\gt m$.

Comment: I could make one definition with more `A`s and one with more `B`s, but then the number of characters is still correlated

Comment: I don't understand your objection. Inequality is also a form of correlation.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood your hint. Could you further elaborate on how to actual implement it?

Comment: But you yourself suggested the solution above ;-) You just need to finish it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Context Free Grammar for language $L=\{a^ib^j \mid i,j \ge 0; i \ne 2j\}$](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9804/context-free-grammar-for-language-l-aibj-mid-i-j-ge-0-i-ne-2j)

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10387/cfg-using-the-set-l-left-a-b-right-for-the-expression-ambn-whe?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @YuvalFilmus thanks. Its not exactly what I need, but through it, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $L = \{a^n b^n : n \in \mathbb N\}$. Your language can be written as $a^+L \cup Lb^+$, and this leads to the following grammar:
$$
\begin{align}
&S \to AT \mid TB \\
&T \to aTb \mid \epsilon \\
&A \to aA \mid a \\
&B \to bB \mid b
\end{align}
$$
We can save a nonterminal by factoring $L$ differently:
$$
L = \{a^na^mb^n : n \geq 0, m \geq 1\} \cup \{a^nb^mb^n : n \geq 0, m \geq 1\}.
$$
This leads to the following grammar:
$$
\begin{align}
&S \to aSb \mid A \mid B \\
&A \to aA \mid a \\
&B \to bB \mid b
\end{align}
$$
There are many other possible variants, for example:
$$
\begin{align}
&S \to A \mid B \\
&A \to aAb \mid aA \mid a \\
&B \to aBb \mid Bb \mid b
\end{align}
$$

Comment: All of your solutions produce the sentences $a^i$ and $b^i$ for $i\ge 1$, although the OP requests $a^ib^j, i,j\ge 1, i\ne j$. Of course, the fixes are minor. For the first one, you can change $T\to aTb\mid\epsilon$ to $T\to aTb\mid ab$.