# Find a context-free grammar for the language $L=\{a^nb^m\mid 2n<m<3n\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I need to find a context-free grammar for the following language which uses the alphabet $\{a, b\}$
$$L=\{a^nb^m\mid 2n<m<3n\}$$

Comment: I tried many solutions by ended with nothing, getting more confused

Comment: This is a dump of a problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: start with the 'classical' CFG: $ S \to aSb $. Consider expanding into one additional non-terminal `B` on the rhs instead ($ S \to aSB $). How could the non-terminal help you reaching your goal ? To exclude the bounds of the range expressed by your inequality, for each bound observe by how many symbols you are off at maximum in any derivation your grammar admits.

Comment: The correct approach to write grammar for the language is write strings first. Understand `n`!=0 and 1.  n should be >= 2. and for n=2.. possible strings are `aabbbbb` only for n=3 strings can be `aaa bbb bbb b`, `aaa bbb bbb bb` for n=4 strings can be `aaaa bbbb bbbb b`, `aaaa bbbb bbbb bb`, `aaaa bbbb bbbb bbb` So for a `n=N` no. of possible strings  are `N-1`. So you need rules like. So rules should be whenever you add one `a` you should add two `Xb`  (where `X` can be replace by `b` or `^`) as `Y --> aYXb` Now In first rule I left `S` to add more  `a`s and `b`s. ... Now --CONTINU..

Comment: Now with min length string that is `aabbb` start with m > 2n as `S --> aaYbbb`. Of-Course add `X --> b | ^`. And To remove `Y` from sentential from add `Y --> a`.

Comment: Try with this explanation. Read [Tips for creating “Context Free Grammar”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126824/tips-for-creating-context-free-grammar/15130451#15130451) To learn other aaproach to write Grmmar. In-case any difficulty let me know.

Comment: Also improve your question and add your work.

Comment: Looks like I have typo in my comment. Actually `Y --> aYXb` should be `Y --> aYXbb` as I am saying add two `b`s from one `a`. -- So to summarize my idea: Start with one extra `a`, latter  add two `b` for one `a`.  Add `X` so that you can add either `b` or `^` to keep `b`'s between 2n to 3n (note you always have more than 2n `b`)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Can you do $$L=\{a^nb^m\mid m=3n\}$$

Try it also for: $$L=\{a^nb^m\mid m=3n-1\}$$

Then you might want to be able not to always have that many $b$.

And there is a bit more to take care of.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a grammar for the language
$$
\{ a^n b^m : 2n \leq m \leq 3n \}
$$
The idea is that if $c_1,\ldots,c_n \in \{2,3\}$ then $2n \leq c_1 + \cdots + c_n \leq 3n$. We can implement this idea in the following way:
$$
S \to aSbb \mid aSbbb \mid \epsilon
$$

Now we want to rule out $m = 2n$ and $m = 3n$. We can enforce this by requiring $c_1 = 2$ and $c_n = 3$ (note that when $n \leq 1$, no $m$ satisfies $2n < m < 3n$). This leads to the following grammar:
$$
S \to aSbb \mid aSbbb \mid aabbbbb
$$

Comment: You hint explains question but *not* helpful for writing grammar. I downvoted as I dislike it in answer section.

Comment: On the contrary, using this idea I can write a grammar for the language.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, ofcourse I knew that you can write a grammar for the language but I believe you have written this answer for *other* users.

Comment: @Grijesh My policy is not to give away answers. I stand by my stance that my hint contains one basic idea behind the solution.

Comment: Yuval I see. Yes I saw many of your answers and I got  your idea.  But I think this question is little bit hard at-least for new uses. So I request you to add some more details so that it can be helpful to write grammar for average users like me... And I saw two more users are disagree with this kind of hints in answer section on [similar question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10928/context-free-grammar-construction/10942#10942) Anyways answer is yours If I disagree I down-vote, If I like vote-up also. my downvotes are very less than up-votes