# Context free grammar for this language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Is this language Context Free?

$L=\{a^{n+3} b^{2m} \mid n \neq m \}$

I think that I could split the languages into $L_1$ and $L_2$ with the conditions $n<m$ and $n>m$, provide 2 CF grammars and then to make the union. But I don't know how to put the condition $n<m$ to the grammar or how to think about the conditions. Thank you!

Comment: [Similar question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23174/find-a-context-free-grammar-for-the-language-l-anbm-mid-2nm3n?rq=1). Hint: it may be easier to construct a PDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea: Construct a Grammar fragment for `$a^nb^(2n)$`. Complement it with rules that break the symmetry.

```
1: L -> aaaX

2: X -> aXbb   // So far, the subsequence of terminals does not belong to L. 
               // The next two rules break the symmetry. 
3: X -> aP
4: X -> Qbb

5: P -> aP  | epsilon
6: Q -> Qbb | epsilon
```

**Proof sketch**

The grammar is clearly context-free.

The correctness can be proven eg. by induction over possible derivations. The intuition is simple:

- Each derivation starts with applying rule 1 followed by an arbitrary number of. applications of rule 2. At each step of this derivation, the current item matches `a^3a^nXb^(2n); n >= 0`. In particular, `n=m`in the nomenclature of the problem statement.
- After application of any one of the rules 3 and 4, non-terminals will only ever expand into sequences of either `a` or `b`.
- At least on application of rule 3 or 4 is necessary to complete a derivation.

The very first application of 3/4 introduces the imbalance between `a` and `bb` in the terminal string. After passing that 'trapdoor', this imbalance will never be offset, since only the 'right' terminals will be produced henceforth.