# Is $L = \{ a^ib^j : 0 < j < i < 2j\}$ context free? How can it be shown?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Is $L = \{ a^ib^j : 0 < j < i < 2j\}$ context free?
If so, can there be a pushdown automaton described for it?
If not, does the pumping lemma apply?

Comment: Your language is context-free. Someone already asked this question on this site, and got a full answer (including a grammar).

Comment: Here is [my answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/23177/683) to a remarkably similar question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10928/755

Answer (score 1):

To show a language is context free we can create a context free grammar for it then show that it generates all strings in the language.

Consider the following grammar $G$.

```
S -> aaaRbb
R -> aRb | aaRb | eps
```

We must prove that $L(G) = L$.

Proof:
The variable $S$ in the grammar starts off with the smallest string in $L$. This string is $aaabb$ with $j=2$ and $i=3$ (since $0 < j = 2 < i = 3 < 2j = 4$).

The repetition happens within the variable $R$. Consider the string $s = a^ib^j \in L$. We want to see whether the string $s' = a^{i+1}b^{j+1}$ is in $L$. The first three conditions are trivial ($0 < j+1 < i+1$). The last condition is quick to check:
\begin{align} 
i+1 &< 2(j+1) \\ 
i+1 &< 2j+2 \\
i &< 2j+1 \\
\end{align}
So $s' \in L$.
We can show $s' = a^{i+2}b^{j+1} \in L$ similarly.

The rules `R -> aaaRb`, `R -> aR`, and `R -> Rb` cannot be in our grammar as it can generate strings that are not in the language. As an example, the strings `aaaaaabb`, `aaaabb`, and `aaabbb` can be generated if we add the above rules which are not in $L$.

Thus, $G$ is complete. Hence, $L(G) = L$.

As for creating a pushdown automata, there are many guides on how to construct a PDA from CFG. The following links will be useful (just from a quick google search).

1. [Convert CFG to CNF](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-context-free-grammar-chomsky-normal-form/)
2. [Convert CFG to GNF](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-context-free-grammar-greibach-normal-form/)
3. [Construct PDA from CFG](https://www.javatpoint.com/automata-cfg-to-pda-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

What's the smallest possible j, and which i goes with it (to allow j < i < 2j). So that's the minimum number of a's and b'. Beyond that, you need one or two a's for every additional b.

That should be enough to find a grammar.